# How can you use the operation symbols ( ,-,*,/) to interact with custom objects?

Tags: java, operators

I'm in AP Comp Sci A, and we are doing a case study called "Grid World". Basically there are bugs and rocks that move (or don't) on a Grid. Each of these "Actors" has a "Location" which is their (row, column) cords as well as their direction. The person who programmed "Grid World" made its so you can add locations togethe4.

If and "Actor" was facing up this would cause it to face to the right:

```
     new Location l = myLocation + Location.HALF_RIGHT;
```

How can I do this to other objects?

Comment: You cannot overload operators in Java, so the above code isn't possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myLocation
```

That's an int.

```
Location.HALF_RIGHT
```

That's an int. You can't add + and - functionality to your objects, but you could add a "add" and "subtract" method.

Also, your code won't even compile. I think you mean:

```
l = new Location(myLocation + Location.HALF_RIGHT);
```

Or, if your result location is an int:

```
l = myLocation + Location.HALF_RIGHT;
```

Comment: The user specifies that `Location` is a class, so `myLocation` should be an object. Probably he wants to know about operator overloading, which is not possible in Java (it is, but we will not tell him)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth just kidding, as you obviously know.

Comment: @Oli well `+` is overloaded for strings ;) No user specific operator overloading though.